# Laravel 4.2 Email::queue with assets

Tags: laravel, supervisord, beanstalkd, mail-queue

Simple, I am trying to queue an email using services beanstalkd and supervisord like so:

```
Mail::queue('emails.congratulations', $user, function($message) use($user) {
    $message->to($user['email'], $user['name'])
        ->subject('Congratulations!');
});
```

My supervisor program config:

```
[program:emailservice]
command=php /path/to/laravel/artisan queue:listen
stdout_logfile=/path/to/laravel/app/storage/logs/emailservice_supervisord.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

In my blade file I am trying to access an asset, an image:

```
<p>
    <img src="{{ asset('assets/img/logo.png') }}" />
</p>
```

When the email is sent and received, the image is broken and the URL to the image looks like this:

```
<img src="http://:/assets/img/logo.png"/>
```

I cannot figure out why the domain is `:`

If anyone else as experienced this behavior it would be good to get this out in the open because I have scoured Google and StackOverflow for answers to this issue without any mention of the issue.

A question I ask myself... when queuing, is Laravel/Supervisor/Beanstalk smart enough to remember the domain for the job?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set application url to your domain (`http://localhost` by default) in config/app.php.

Comment: Yeah, we have `'url' => 'http://domain.com',` but the helper function is still using '**:**'. Its not even using `http://localhost`. The URL looks like this `<img src="http://:/assets/img/logo.png"/>`