# Laravel 5.2 queue ignores .env

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.2 app which sends a few emails when a user buys a product.  The email view includes references to some images, like so:

```
<img src="{{ asset($purchase->image) }}">
```

This works fine in all 3 environments I have - local, staging, and production.  `asset()` correctly constructs the fully qualified URLs to the appropriate image, using the configured APP_URLs in each environment.

I decided to switch to using [Laravel queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues) to send the emails.

- I changed the `QUEUE_DRIVER` in `.env` to `database`
- `php artisan queue:table`
- `php artisan migrate`
- `php artisan queue:listen`
- Changed

  ```
  \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::send(
  ```

  to

  ```
  \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::queue(
  ```

and made a test purchase.  The process works, the mail is sent, but the image URLs in the delivered emails are wrong.  It seems that my configured APP_URL is not being picked up.

**.env**

```
APP_URL=http://localhost/path/to/app
```

**config/app.php**

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
```

The URLs `asset()` generates in my email are:

```
http://localhost/images/foo.jpg
```

which is incorrect, they should be:

```
http://localhost/path/to/app/images/foo.jpg
```

It looks like using queues the `APP_URL` defined in my `.env` is not seen, so the default of `http://localhost` is used.  Not using queues, the same code works fine.

The only thing I can think of is that the CLI PHP environment which is handling the queue is somehow different from the Apache PHP environment, but I can't imagine what difference would cause `.env` to be ignored.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041896/laravel-4-2-emailqueue-with-assets) from someone using Laravel 4.2, 2 years ago, with no answer.  I found a few other similar references but no solution.  Anyone seen this or have any suggestions?

Comment: I know it's stupid. But how about `env('APP_URL').'/images/'.$purchase->image` p.s. it's just workaround, maybe for commandline executions it needs different env file? Can You check `asset` method's code?

Comment: In fact this issue still exist: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14139

Comment: Thanks @num8er, my Googling didn't turn up that issue. Let me check it out a bit more ... yes I can workaround, in fact maybe that's all I can do.  It is strange that it is not more common though, surely I am not the only person using `asset()` in queued emails?

Comment: I think this problem still not fixed. In my custom artisan console commands I always user exact paths, urls and etc. because of this issue that never was working as is.

Comment: Thanks, guess that's what I have to do ... thanks for you help!

Comment: @num8er I know it is late but your comment is really the answer - it is a bug.  If you want to repost it as an answer I'd be happy to accept it! :-)

Comment: Thanks) I'm not hunting for upvotes) just trying to be helpful. Just summarize Your solution and answer to You own question with solution, to be helpful to ones who came here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @num8er for finding the solution.

This is a known problem in Laravel that comes from Symfony: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14139

A workaround is to do as @num8er suggested in the comments, and hard-code asset paths in views, rather than use `asset()`:

```
config('app.url') . '/images/' . $purchase->image
```